# Android app: ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut error

Tags: android

Any suggestions for this kind of error which occurs when a UI thread is loaded with lots of loops and logical operations?

Comment: You should read this; [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the error message through data/anr/trace.txt from File explorer. And, also put all logical operations and loops into separate threads.

Answer (score 0):

That ANR error happens when you are doing intensive work on UI thread and do not allow the user interface to refresh. Your description is a perfect match for this case.

To fix it run those operations on a different thread. You can also use AsyncTask if that's convenient in your situation. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

```
private class LongWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
```

{

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

  //Do a long Task here
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
```

//Do what you have to do on the UI Thread

```
}
```

}

Then

```
LongWork work=new LongWork();
work.execute();
```